# Sightengine API not working correctly?

Tags: php

I have recently come across an API called Sightengine which checks images for nudity, violence and some more things. I have followed their site to set up this API and got the following code in my PHP-file:

```
require __DIR__."/../Sightengine/src/SightengineClient.php";
require __DIR__."/../Sightengine/src/Check.php";

$filterImage = new Sightengine\SightengineClient('189981095', '5snnKqMiPU8cx2fHuUff');
$resultFilterImage = $filterImage->check(['nudity'])->set_url('https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/examples/example7.jpg');
```

Now, this should work and give back a JSON with information in it about how nude the picture is, but when trying to run this, it gives me the follow error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzeleHttp\Client' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ugesco\Sightengine\src\SightengineClient.php:13
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdcos\ugesco\Controller\controller.php(234):
Sightengine\SightengineClient-&gt;__construct('my user key', 'my pass key')
#1 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ugesco\Sightengine\src\SightengineClient.php on line 13
```

Now, what I get out of this is that the class GuzzleHttp\Client can't be found in the SightengineClient.php-file. Thing is, I copied this from the Sightengine-company their Github, so I have no clue why it is not there..?

This is the code in the SightengineClient.php:

```
<?php
namespace Sightengine;

class SightengineClient  { 
    private $api_user;
    private $api_secret;
    private $endpoint = 'https://api.sightengine.com/';
    private $http;

    function __construct($api_user, $api_secret) {
      $this->api_user = $api_user;
      $this->api_secret = $api_secret;
      $this->http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $this->endpoint, 'User-Agent' => 'SE-SDK-PHP' . '1.0']);
    }

    public function feedback($model, $modelClass, $image) {
        $url = '1.0/feedback.json';

        if (filter_var($image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { 
            $r = $this->http->request('GET', $url, ['query' => ['api_user' => $this->api_user, 'api_secret' => $this->api_secret, 'model' => $model,'class' => $modelClass,'url' => $image]]);

        return json_decode($r->getBody());
      } 
      else {
               $file = fopen($image, 'r');
         $r = $this->http->request('POST', $url, ['query' => ['api_user' => $this->api_user, 'api_secret' => $this->api_secret, 'model' => $model,'class' => $modelClass],'multipart' => [['name' => 'media','contents' => $file]]]); 

        return json_decode($r->getBody());
          }
    }

    public function check($models) {
      return new Check($this->api_user, $this->api_secret, $models);
    }
}
```

As you can see on line 13 it wants to make a new GuzzeleHttp\Client but that Client-class is nowhere to be found. You can check their Github yourself: https://github.com/Sightengine/client-php

This is a real company who offers packages of image checks for money, so how could this be that their code is not working anymore (or is this an easy fix?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: install GuzzleHttp/client

Comment: Hey, I don't really get what this "GuzzleHttp/Client actually is and where I should find it to install..?

Comment: I have now used the composer to get the code for the Sightengine. It still gives errors about not finding that GuzzleHttp/Client-class.. Should I do includes somewhere?

How come that it doesn't auto include all these things?

Answer (score 0):

It does work if you perform a proper install using composer:

`composer require sightengine/client-php`

`guzzlehttp/guzzle` is correctly listed as a dependency in the composer.json file: https://github.com/Sightengine/client-php/blob/master/composer.json